# SQL Server exec result into variable

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I get a linked server in SQL Server, I must create a trigger after insert and update using values that I recover from  linked server.

When I run my script, I can get the value, using parameters, but when I try to use that value for updating a record, the field updates whit the query string and not with the result of that query string.

This is part of my code:

```
DECLARE @DWDOCID INT

SELECT @DWDOCID = DWDOCID 
FROM inserted

DECLARE @NUMERO_FORMULARIO VARCHAR(150)
DECLARE @ID_TITULAR VARCHAR(150)

SET @NUMERO_FORMULARIO = '200001001' 
SET @ID_TITULAR = '1050554243'

DECLARE @NOMBRE VARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @OPENQUERY NVARCHAR(4000), 
        @LinkedServer NVARCHAR(250)

SET @LinkedServer = 'MYSQLT'
SET @OPENQUERY = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+ @LinkedServer + ','''
SET @NOMBRE = 'SELECT nombre FROM vistaBell WHERE codigo_contrato = ''''' + @NUMERO_FORMULARIO + ''''' and id_titular = ''''' + @ID_TITULAR + ''''''')'

EXEC (@OPENQUERY + @NOMBRE)
```

If I print `@NOMBRE`, I get the correct values, but if I try to use it:

```
UPDATE FLUJO_AFILIACIÓN_Y_CONTRA
SET APELLIDOS_Y_NOMBRES_DE_TITULA = @NOMBRE
WHERE DWDOCID = @DWDOCID
```

The result is the string query in the field. My SQL Server version is 2008 R2.

Please, I hope anyone can help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solution is create a type table variable, in that variable insert the EXEC result.
after that you can get that values in another variables and use them for updating, insert, or whatever.

```
        DECLARE @afiliado varchar(250) = NULL
        DECLARE @idcontra varchar(250) = NULL
        DECLARE @inivigen date = NULL
        DECLARE @t TABLE (nomAfi VARCHAR(250), idCont VARCHAR(250), iniVig DATE)
        INSERT INTO @t EXEC (@OPENQUERY + @NOMBRE)
        SELECT @afiliado = nomAfi FROM @t
        SELECT @idcontra = idCont FROM @t
        SELECT @inivigen = iniVig FROM @t               
        ---------

        UPDATE FLUJO_AFILIACIÓN_Y_CONTRA
        SET APELLIDOS_Y_NOMBRES_DE_TITULA = @afiliado, ID_CONTRATANTE = @idcontra,
        FECHA_INICIO_VIGENCIA = @inivigen, ACTUALIZADO = 'SI'
        WHERE DWDOCID = @DWDOCID
```

I only have one question: when SQL Server uses that variable (@t) for example for updating once commit transaction, SQL Server delete that variable? destroy its value? or something like that?

thanks